# Объединение в MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

У меня есть две таблицы

```
1) Id        Name       Id_Proffesia
    1        Denis          2
    2        Alex           2

2) Id        Professia
    1        Programmist
    2        Ingener
```

Первая база данных будет достаточно большой (100.000 записей).  Мне нужно вывести id, имя человека и его профессия, вот так:

```
 2      Alex           Ingener
```

У меня только один вопрос: каким способом лучше это сделать (Join,  вложенным запросом или через переменную @)?

Comment: такого рода запрос через JOIN в таблицу с записями >12к у меня заняло 0.0015 сек... причем у меня запросы идут не в две, а в три таблицы... с двумя join-ами

Comment: Еще, для поля `Id_Proffesia` должен быть установлен индекс, или, еще лучше, внешний ключ.

Answer (score 4):

Вот так:

```
select u.id, u.Name, p.Professia
from users as u 
left join prof as p on u.Id_Professia = p.id
```

Это стандартный вид запроса для таких связей. Так если у вас, например, еще будет таблица с образованием, то добавите дополнительный `left join`.

Именно `left join`. Т.к. если у вас окажется в один прекрасный момент, что профессия не задана (null), то в случае связки по `join` вы этих юзеров не увидите.

Comment: В целом понятно. Большое  спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `join` для объединения таблиц

```
select 
    tbl1.*, tbl2.Professia 
from tbl1 
inner join tbl2 on tbl1.Id_Proffesia = tbl2.id 
limit 30;
```